# Issues while connecting containers in different Google Cloud clusters

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have two clusters at Google Cloud Kubernetes.

The two clusters have different version. Cluster A is 1.6.4 and B is 1.6.7. When they were at both version (1.6.4), i was able to communicate (send HTTPS requests) with containers in this cluster. After upgrading cluster B, i can send a HTTPS request from B to A.

Have someone found this?

Comment: Are you getting any error message? post some error informaiton.

Comment: Not get any information. If i try to wget a file from cluster B to A, i see "Connecting" and never return nothing. Like a hanging